# Editing tabs HTML/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I need help in create template html  - I want add 7 tabs to right, left and footer page, but I don't know how make this. Thank you in advance! Code here:

jQuery:

```
var Nav = (function() {
  var
    nav         = $('.css-tab'),
    section = $('.section'),
    link        = nav.find('.css-tab__link'),
    navH        = nav.innerHeight(),
    isOpen  = true,
    hasT        = false;

  var toggleNav = function() {
    nav.toggleClass('css-tab--active');
    shiftPage();
  };


  var switchPage = function(e) {
    var self = $(this);
    var i = self.parents('.css-tab__item').index();
    var s = section.eq(i);
    var a = $('section.section--active');
    var t = $(e.target);

    if (!hasT) {
      if (i == a.index()) {
        return false;
      }
      a
      .addClass('section--hidden')
      .removeClass('section--active');

      s.addClass('section--active');

      hasT = true;

      a.on('transitionend webkitTransitionend', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('section--hidden');
        hasT = false;
        a.off('transitionend webkitTransitionend');
      });
    }

    return false;
  };

  var keyNav = function(e) {
    var a = $('section.section--active');
    var aNext = a.next();
    var aPrev = a.prev();
    var i = a.index();


    if (!hasT) {
      if (e.keyCode === 37) {

        if (aPrev.length === 0) {
          aPrev = section.last();
        }

        hasT = true;

        aPrev.addClass('section--active');
        a
          .addClass('section--hidden')
          .removeClass('section--active');

        a.on('transitionend webkitTransitionend', function() {
          a.removeClass('section--hidden');
          hasT = false;
          a.off('transitionend webkitTransitionend');
        });

      } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {

        if (aNext.length === 0) {
          aNext = section.eq(0)
        } 


        aNext.addClass('section--active');
        a
          .addClass('section--hidden')
          .removeClass('section--active');

        hasT = true;

        aNext.on('transitionend webkitTransitionend', function() {
          a.removeClass('section--hidden');
          hasT = false;
          aNext.off('transitionend webkitTransitionend');
        });

      } else {
        return
      }
    }  
  };

  var bindActions = function() {
    link.on('click', switchPage);
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
       page.css({
        'transform': 'translateY(' + navH + 'px)',
         '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(' + navH + 'px)'
      });
    });
    $('body').on('keydown', keyNav);
  };

  var init = function() {
    bindActions();
  };

  return {
    init: init
  };

}());

Nav.init();
```

**CSS**:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "futura-pt", 'Century Gothic', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  color: #fff;
  background: #1a1a1a;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.css-tab {
  will-change: transform;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
          transform: translateY(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.css-tab--active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
          transform: translateY(0);
}
.css-tab__list {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.css-tab__item {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.css-tab__item:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.css-tab__thumb {
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  background: #dc143c;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.css-tab__thumb:before {
  content: attr(data-letter);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0;
}
.css-tab__label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  margin: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 850px) {
  .css-tab__label {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .css-tab__label {
    display: none;
  }
  .css-tab__thumb {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .css-tab__thumb:before {
    font-size: 24px;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
}
.tab-content {
  height: 100vh;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-perspective: 400px;
          perspective: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.section {
  will-change: transform;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.section--hidden {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.section--active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0);
          transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0);
  z-index: 2;
}
.section__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0 8vw;
  position: relative;
}
.section__title {
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.section__title:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5rem;
  left: 45%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 10%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .section__title {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .section__title:before {
    top: 3.25rem;
  }
}
.section p {
  margin: 0 0 25px 0;
  font-family: 'Georgia';
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.55;
}
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .section p {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
.section p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.color1 {
  background: #1b1f25;
}
.color2 {
  background: #e74c3c;
}
.color3 {
  background: #3498db;
}
.color4 {
  background: #9b59b6;
}
.color5 {
  background: #1bc885;
}
.color6 {
  background: #dfb816;
}
.color7 {
  background: #008B8B;
}
.logo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .logo {
    top: 110px;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -20px;
  }
}
.logo img {
  width: 45px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
          transform: rotate(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  transition: all 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.logo img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1.1);
          transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1.1);
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<nav class="css-tab css-tab--active">
  <ul class="css-tab__list">
    <li class="css-tab__item">
      <a href="" class="css-tab__link">
        <div class="css-tab__thumb color1" data-letter="1"></div>
        <p class="css-tab__label">1</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="css-tab__item">
      <a href="" class="css-tab__link">
        <div class="css-tab__thumb color2" data-letter="2"></div>
        <p class="css-tab__label">2</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="css-tab__item">
      <a href="" class="css-tab__link">
        <div class="css-tab__thumb color3" data-letter="3"></div>
        <p class="css-tab__label">3</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="css-tab__item">
      <a href="" class="css-tab__link">
        <div class="css-tab__thumb color4" data-letter="4"></div>
        <p class="css-tab__label">4</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="css-tab__item">
      <a href="" class="css-tab__link">
        <div class="css-tab__thumb color5" data-letter="5"></div>
        <p class="css-tab__label">5</p>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="css-tab__item">
      <a href="" class="css-tab__link">
        <div class="css-tab__thumb color6" data-letter="6"></div>
        <p class="css-tab__label">6</p>
      </a>
    </li>
     <li class="css-tab__item">
      <a href="" class="css-tab__link">
        <div class="css-tab__thumb color7" data-letter="7"></div>
        <p class="css-tab__label">7</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>


   <a href="http://www.jquery-az.com" class="logo" target="_blank">
   <img class="logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/45226/ettrics-logo.svg" alt="" /> 
  </a>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content">
  <section class="section section--active color1" data-letter="a">
    <article class="section__wrapper">
      <h1 class="section__title">1</h1>
      <section id="about">
              <h2><a href="#about">1</a></h2>
              <p>Test
              </p>
          </section>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="section color2" data-letter="p">
    <article class="section__wrapper">
      <h1 class="section__title">2</h1>
      <p>2</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="section color3" data-letter="q">
    <article class="section__wrapper">
      <h1 class="section__title">3</h1>
      <p>3</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="section color4" data-letter="e">
    <article class="section__wrapper">
      <h1 class="section__title">4</h1>
      <p>4</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="section color5" data-letter="s">
    <article class="section__wrapper">
      <h1 class="section__title">5</h1>
      <p>5</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="section color6">
    <article class="section__wrapper">
      <h1 class="section__title">6</h1>
      <p>7</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <section class="section color7">
    <article class="section__wrapper">
      <h1 class="section__title">7</h1>
      <p>7</p>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

I will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you use a library like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) or material for creating this? Or you can use [Material With Angular](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/navBar). Using a framework is handy and more helpful when it comes to community help and documentation.